# Stop Microsoft Excel 2007 from formatting anything?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, cell-format

How can I stop Excel 2007 from modifying any character, I don't want to modify the date in any way, I don't want to modify misspells, nothing.

I just want to see the exact text I'm writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefix your data with a ', it will display as is.  That is:

> '12:00

Comment: Thanks, but does this work only for date, or for anything, for example currency?

Comment: @GabiDiaconescu: I believe so, but I'm not sure as I don't have Excel on this PC.  It's only function is to leave entries unformated.  I don't see why there should be exceptions to the type of entry this applies to.